# Изменение размеров блоков на флексах

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Есть восемь блоков на флексах, нужно их сделать 200х200px по центру **адаптивно!**

4 блока в одной строке. Desktop-версия.
При мобильной версии все блоки один под одним:

```css
.main_blocks {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 1200px;
}

.main_blocks div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_blocks">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
  <div class="item4"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="item5"></div>
  <div class="item6"></div>
  <div class="item7"></div>
  <div class="item8"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main_blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.main_blocks div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .main_blocks {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main_blocks">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
  <div class="item4"></div>

  <div class="item5"></div>
  <div class="item6"></div>
  <div class="item7"></div>
  <div class="item8"></div>
</div>
```